# CodeRunner new statement position

Tags: coderunner

I'm new to CodeRunner and I was wondering if there is a way to have the cursor to place itself at the same position that the last statement when pressing enter to start a variable declaration statement, so that they all start at the same position even if the first statement is indented.

I've tried everything and I can't find a way

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The latest update to CodeRunner (v2.1.1) fixed this issue you're having. Additionally, you can keep things indented within the same space by tabbing the first line's position to where you want. Each proceeding line will fall in place relative to the first line's position.